# What does it mean for a formula of set theory to exist?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

First, I need to give a little context.  On p. 222 of his [*Classic Set Theory*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Classic_Set_Theory/1dLn0knvZSsC?hl=en), Derek Goldrei writes:

> ***Theorem 8.9 The recursion principle for ordinals***
> Let $\phi(x, y, z)$ be a formula of set theory such that for each ordinal $\beta$ and
> set $y$ there is a unique set $z$ such that $\phi(\beta, y, z)$ holds.  Thus $\phi$ essentially defines a class function $$h: \mathcal{O}\times\mathcal{V}\longrightarrow\mathcal{V}\;,$$ where $\mathcal{O}$ is the class of all ordinals and $\mathcal{V}$ is the universe of sets. Let $\delta$ be an ordinal. Then there is a unique function $f$ with domain $\delta$ such that for every $\beta\in\delta$,$$f(\beta)=h(\beta,f|_\beta)\,.$$

Later in the book (pp. 223-224), Goldrei writes (my emphasis):

> It is pretty usual for books at this level to present the definition of a function $f$ on an ordinal using transfinite recursion fairly informally, without giving any detail of the formula $\phi$ involved, or the corresponding class function $h$ (in the notation of Theorem 8.9). But for further studies in set theory, it is often important to look at the structure, e.g. the logical complexity, of the $\phi$ — as well as *to be sure that such a $\phi$ really exists!*

**Questions:** *What does it mean for a "formula of set theory"*<sup>1</sup> *to exist?*  Is it possible to give an example of a formula of set theory that does *not* exist?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> FWIW, I think that a "formula of set theory" is just a formula consisting of the usual symbols of first-order logic, variables (representing sets), and the special symbol $\in$.</sup>

Comment: A *formula* is an expression of the language: a string od symbols correctly written according to the syntactical rules of the language: $(x \in y)$ and so on.

Comment: "Is it possible to give an example of a formula of set theory that does not exist?" NO, we may have "incorrectly written" formulas (not well-formed), like e.g. $(\in x)$.

Comment: IMO the author means: "a formula $ϕ(x,y,z)$ such that the specified property holds", i.e. such that: "for each ordinal β and set y there is a unique set z such that ϕ(β,y,z) hold".

Comment: Consider e.g. the formula $\forall x (x \in a)$. This formula "exists" (we have written it according to the rules of the language) but it specifies a set that (in some set theories) does not exist: the "universal" set.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Thank you!  From your second comment I assume that you mean that every correctly written formula, ipso facto, exists: our ability to determine that a formula is correctly written *depends* on this formula's existence.  Therefore, to exhibit a formula that, simultaneously, is correctly written and does not exist, would be simply self-contradictory. (continues)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: (continuing) Therefore, your second comment seems to me to imply that you interpret the phrase that I emphasized in my second excerpt as being equivalent with "to be sure that one can produce a correctly written $\phi$."  Your third comment, however, says something stronger: not only must $\phi$ be correctly written in order for it to exist, but it also has to hold (in contrast to, say, $\forall{x}(x\in{a})$ which is correctly written, but holds for no $a$).

Comment: Couldn't t it be said that the formula $\forall x(x\in a)\Leftrightarrow a=V$. And hence wouldn't the formula $\forall x(x\in a)$ really be a formula describing the proper class of all sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the author writes that we need to "be sure that such a $\varphi$ really exists", he just means that we need to make sure we can actually write down a formula that has the specified properties.

By analogy, I might write "we need to make sure that a prime number greater than $100$ really exists" and then produce $103$ as an example. By writing this, I am not suggesting that there are prime numbers greater than $100$ that do not exist!

In general, in mathematics, existence is not a predicate. We can ask whether there exists an object with certain properties, but given a particular object $x$, it makes no sense to ask whether $x$ exists.

Comment: I find your answers very helpful Professor Kruckman. I am still learning, so could you elaborate on the last sentence? I understand that we may ask whether an object with certain properties exists, but I do not quite understand why it is meaningless to consider the existence of a particular object. Is it that the only way to refer to an object formally is precisely by its defining properties?

Comment: @Alex My point is just there are *not* some things that exist and other things that don't exist. Every thing exists (by virtue of being a thing).

Comment: Thank you!  Just to be clear, would it be fair to say that, in this case, "the specified properties" that we must ensure the formula we write down has boil down to "for each ordinal $\beta$ and set $y$ there is a unique set $z$ such that $\phi(\beta, y, z)$"?

Comment: @kjo Yes, that's right.